# Runnable interface instantiation

Tags: java, oop, java-8

I am following the book Head first java and was reading about threads and came to know about the Runnable interface. Now we know an interface can't be instantiated directly. Its members are implemented by any class that implements the interface , but below code made bouncers over my head. The book declares the instance of the Runnable interface and assign the object of the implementing class of the runnable interface.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   public void main() {
        go();
   }
   public void go() {
        doMore();
   }
   public void doMore() {
     System.out.println("top of the stack");
   }
}

class ThreadTester {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Runnable threadJob = new MyRunnable();
      Thread myThread = new Thread(threadJob);
      myThread.start();
      System.out.println("back in pain");
  }
}
```

I couldn't understand the line `Runnable threadJob = new MyRunnable();` . How an interface being instantiated when it is not allowed. Why can't be the line like  `MyRunnable threadJob = new MyRunnable();` . I mean MyRunnable class passes the IS-A test for Runnable interface so why author chose the former statement. Is that something I am missing here. Please help me clarify.

Comment: It's a matter of relationship between the two types. Because `MyRunnable` inherits from or implements `Runnable`, we say that *MyRunnable **is a** Runnable*, which means that where the target variable is of type `Runnable`, it's allowed to assign a `MyRunnable` object (*is a* denotes compatibility)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now we know an interface can't be instantiated **directly.**

You're not instantiating the `Runnable` interface directly.

Hopefully you agree that the following should work:

```
MyRunnable threadJob = new MyRunnable();
Runnable runnable = threadJob; // since threadJob is a Runnable
```

So why shouldn't that line work?

When we say that you can't instantiate an interface directly, what that means is that you can't write

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable();
```

That's the only thing that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

**in OOP call that polymorphism.**
it say you can for instantiating from  `classB` (assume `ClassB` is subclass of `ClassA`) define variable with `ClassA` type, and then instantiating from `ClassB` and assign it to that variable.
for example in java Object class is root of any classes so you can do it like below:

```
Object x = new YourClass();
```

or if for example your class `implements` `InterfaceA` you can do it like here:

```
InterfaceA x = new YourClass();
```